# Word Count of .resx files

Tags: .net, globalization

we will be processing our .resx files for translation. Since these files have lots of xml data apart from strings to be translated, I was looking for a way where we can count the words/strings that are translated. We have winform created resx file

Thanks.

Comment: Since .RESX are XML files, you could also use XSLT:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188189/count-the-number-of-words-in-a-xml-node-using-xsl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look for properties named Text and other properties that represent the translatable strings you care about.

```
System.Resources.ResXResourceReader reader = new System.Resources.ResXResourceReader(@"..\..\Form1.resx");
foreach(System.Collections.DictionaryEntry de in reader)
{
   if (((string)de.Key).EndsWith(".Text"))
   {
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("{0}: {1}", de.Key, de.Value));
   }
}
```

Comment: Just to note that you need to include a Framework Assembly Reference to System.Windows.Forms.dll to be able to use the ResXResourceReader class.