# count the number of words in a xml node using xsl

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is the sample xml document.

```
<root>
  <node> count the number of words </node>
</root>
```

For this example I want to count the number of words in the node "" in xslt.

The output like be Number of words:: 5

Any idea for this?

Your (Dimitre Novatchev) code is working fine for the above xml.
Is your code will work for the following xml?

```
<root>

<test>
   <node> pass pass </node>
</test>

  <test>
      <node> fail pass fail </node>
  </test>

  <test>
      <node> pass pass fail </node>
  </test>

 </root>
```

output like be: total number of words in the node "node": 8

Update3::

This code perfectly working for the above xml doc.
Suppose

```
<root>
<test>
   <node> pass pass </node>
   <a> value </a>
   <b> value </b>
</test>

  <test>
      <node> fail fail </node>
      <b> value </b>
  </test>

  <test>
      <node> pass pass</node>
      <a> value </a>
  </test>
 </root>
```

But yours code count the number of words in the entire document.
I want to count the number of words in the node type "node" only.
The output like

Number of words in "node" :: 6
Total Pass:: 4
Total Fail:: 2

Thanx
Sathish

Comment: Which XSLT processor are you using?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a short and simple one-liner-XPath-expression solution :)

Comment: updated answer to reflect changes please check it out sathish!

Comment: @Sathish: See my *Update1* for a solution of your modified problem. :)

Comment: @Sathish: For your *third* question (made in a comment) see my *Update2* :) I think that it is best you stop modifying your question. Ask additional questions as ... new questions (you can let me know that you posted a new question via a comment). Your question, and more than this has been fully answered.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Use this XPath one-liner**:

```
  string-length(normalize-space(node)) 
- 
  string-length(translate(normalize-space(node),' ','')) +1
```

**Here is a short verification using XSLT**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   " string-length(normalize-space(node))
    -
     string-length(translate(normalize-space(node),' ','')) +1"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<root>
    <node> count the number of words </node>
</root>
```

the wanted, correct result is produced:

```
5
```

**Explanation**: Use of the standard XPath functions [**`normalize-space()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-normalize-space), [**`translate()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-translate) and [**`string-length()`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string-length) .

**Update1**:

The OP asked:

> "Your (Dimitre Novatchev) code is
>   working fine for the above xml. Is
>   your code will work for the following
>   xml?"
>
> ```
> <root>
>   <test>
>       <node> pass pass </node>
>   </test>
>   <test>
>       <node> fail pass fail </node>
>   </test>
>   <test>
>       <node> pass pass fail </node>
>   </test>
> </root>
> ```

**Answer**: The same approach can be used:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:value-of select=
        "string-length(normalize-space(.))
        -
         string-length(translate(normalize-space(.),' ','')) +1
         "/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is used on the newly-provided XML document (above), the wanted correct answer is produced**:

```
8
```

**Update2**: The OP then asked in a comment:

> "Can I have a comparision with the
>   words in the node with some default
>   word. Conside node contains value
>   `"pass pass fail"`. I want to calculate
>   number of pass and number of fail.
>   LIke `pass=2 fail=1`. is it possible?
>   Help me man"

**Answer**:

The same approach works with this modification of the problem, too (in the general case, though. you need a good tokenization -- ask me about this in a new question, please):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node">
        pass: <xsl:value-of select=
                "string-length()
                -
                 string-length(translate(.,'p',''))
         "/>
<xsl:text/>     fail: <xsl:value-of select=
                "string-length()
                -
                 string-length(translate(.,'f',''))
         "/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the last XML document (above), the wanted, correct is produced:**

```
    pass: 2     fail: 0
    pass: 1     fail: 2
    pass: 2     fail: 1
```

Comment: very nice although if the node just has whitespace and no words you still get a value of 1 :P

Comment: Can I have a comparision with the words in the node with some default word. Conside node contains value "pass pass fail".         I want to calculate number of pass and number of fail. LIke pass=2 fail=1. is it possible? Help me man.

Comment: @Sathish: I have updated my answer to include solutions to your two additional solutions -- using the same approach produces very short and simple solutions -- do have a look. :)

Comment: @Sathish: I always try and verify that my solutions are producing the correct answer. You simply need to copy and paste the XML and XSLT and then run the transformation -- you should get the same result as I am getting. If not, this means that either your XSLT processor is buggy/incompliant, or you have made some error in the copy/paste or you are applying the transformation not on the XML that you provided in the question. See which of these cases applies to you and correct accordingly.

Comment: as the one liner is written in two lines, it's a bit confusing (looks like alternative solutions)

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis, I have a standard of good code formatting, to achieve readability so that the reader doesn't have to scroll horizontally. This doesn't eliminate the need to read and understand the expressions.

Answer (score 1):

in xslt i think you would need to process to remove any double spacing and then count the remaining spaces to find an answer. although im sure there are better ways!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each select="node">
                <xsl:call-template name="word-count">
                        <xsl:with-param name="data" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="num" select="1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="word-count">
            <xsl:param name="data"/>
            <xsl:param name="num"/>
            <xsl:variable name="newdata" select="$data"/>
            <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($newdata,' ')"/>                

            <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$remaining">
                            <xsl:call-template name="word-count">
                                    <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$remaining"/>
                                    <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num+1"/>
                            </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:when test="$num = 1">
                            no words...
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="$num"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>                
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

this example code works, ammended it from a stylesheet i had which was processing some legacy code into usefull html output!

updated code to improve against errors, catches duplicate whitespace and also catches empty nodes :>

Updated to solve additional problem!

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="html"/>

        <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each select="test/node">
                <xsl:call-template name="word-count">
                        <xsl:with-param name="data" select="normalize-space(.)"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="num" select="1"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="pass" select="0"/>
                        <xsl:with-param name="fail" select="0"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="word-count">
        <xsl:param name="data"/>
        <xsl:param name="num"/>
        <xsl:param name="fail"/>
        <xsl:param name="pass"/>
        <xsl:variable name="newdata" select="$data"/>
        <xsl:variable name="first">
                <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="substring-before($newdata,' ')">
                                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($newdata,' ')"/>  
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$newdata"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable> 
        <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($newdata,' ')"/>
        <xsl:variable name="newpass">
                <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$first='pass'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$pass+1"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$pass"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>        
        <xsl:variable name="newfail">
                <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$first='fail'">
                                <xsl:value-of select="$fail+1"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="$fail"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$remaining">
                        <xsl:call-template name="word-count">                        
                                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$remaining"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num+1"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="pass" select="$newpass"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="fail" select="$newfail"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$num = 1">
                        it was empty
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$first"/>
                        wordcount:<xsl:value-of select="$num"/>
                        pass:<xsl:value-of select="$newpass"/>
                        fail:<xsl:value-of select="$newfail"/><br/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an XSLT I was just building based on the answer by Dimitre Novatchev above.
It's counting words under root/data/value (this is for .NET resource files [.RESX]), but you can easily adapt it.

Regarding the node-set function it uses, see the URL mentioned in the XSLT on how to do it with EXSLT enabled processors or others that support this function natively (the use of the msxml namespace is for .NET/MSXML, can easily change that to refer to EXSLT etc.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!--
Filename: ResX_WordCount.xsl
Version: 20141006
-->

<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  >

  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <!-- see http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/07/16/nodeset.html -->
    <xsl:variable name="WordCounts">
      <xsl:for-each select="data/value">
        <!-- see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188189/count-the-number-of-words-in-a-xml-node-using-xsl/ -->
        <count>
          <xsl:value-of select="string-length(normalize-space(text())) - string-length(translate(normalize-space(text()),' ','')) + 1"/>
        </count>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:value-of select="sum(msxsl:node-set($WordCounts)/count)"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```