# Count number of lines in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

When transforming this XML, I need to count the number of line breaks in this XML node

```
    <SpecialInstraction>One
Two
Three
Four
Five
Six
Seven
Eight
Nine
Ten
Eleven
twelve
thirteen
fourteen
fifteen</SpecialInstraction>
```

Like above example have 14 line breaks.

I tried to determine the number of occurrences of "`&#xD;&#xA;`" and "`&#13;`" but even if there is no change in above XML, the number of occurrences keep varying everytime this XML goes under serialization/deserialization.

Anybody has any ideas how I can get the count of lines from value of an XML node in XSLT?

Answer (score 1):

**Use**:

```
string-length() - string-length(translate(., '&#xA;', ''))
```

**Although by using the above XPath one-liner, you don't need XSLT at all, for comleteness here is it**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="text()">
     <xsl:value-of select=
     "string-length() - string-length(translate(., '&#xA;', ''))"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<SpecialInstraction>One
    Two
    Three
    Four
    Five
    Six
    Seven
    Eight
    Nine
    Ten
    Eleven
    twelve
    thirteen
    fourteen
    fifteen</SpecialInstraction>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
14
```

**Do note**:

This solution onlu counts the number of NL characters. Why did I ignore the CRs? Simply because according to the **[W3C XML Specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/)**, any compliant XML parser must do the following:

> *all #xD characters literally present in an XML document are either removed or replaced by #xA characters before any other processing is
>   done.*

Answer (score 0):

There was a similar question on [StackOverflow - (count the number of words in a xml node using xsl)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6188189/count-the-number-of-words-in-a-xml-node-using-xsl)  for counting the number of spaces in a string. I've adapted the code a little stolen from there to use newlines.

```
<xsl:template name="word-count">
        <xsl:param name="data"/>
        <xsl:param name="num"/>
        <xsl:variable name="newdata" select="$data"/>
        <xsl:variable name="remaining" select="substring-after($newdata,'&#10;')"/>                

        <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$remaining">
                        <xsl:call-template name="word-count">
                                <xsl:with-param name="data" select="$remaining"/>
                                <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num+1"/>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="$num = 1">
                        no words...
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="$num"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>                
</xsl:template>
```